# VBA program to search a dictionary text file to see if a word is there is not functioning correctly

Tags: vba

I'm learning programming, and having problems with a program I wrote in VBA, but I can't figure out where I went wrong. Sorry if this is too basic than what you usually deal with, but VBA is much harder to learn than Python and I'm having tonnes of problems with it, so if you can point out the error I will be grateful. Sorry if this is in the wrong area.

It sometimes gives false positives, such as when "Computer" is inputed returning "conspirantFound!", but I can't figure out why.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Ne()

    Dim PathString As String
    Dim Filenum As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim word As String
    Dim searchword As String
    Dim Wordfound As Boolean


    searchword = InputBox("Input your word")
    LCase (searchword)

    PathString = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
    Filenum = FreeFile()

    Open PathString + "\dictionary.txt" For Input As Filenum

    Wordfound = False

    For i = 1 To 10000

        Input #Filenum, word

        If word = searchword Then

            Wordfound = True

        Else

            Next i

        End If

           If Wordfound = True Then MsgBox word + "Found" Else MsgBox ("Word not Found")
    Close Filenum
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```
Sub sof20262258Ne()

  Dim PathString As String
  Dim Filenum As Integer
  Dim word As String
  Dim searchword As String
  Dim Wordfound As Boolean

  searchword = InputBox("Input your word")
  searchword = LCase(searchword)

  PathString = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
  Filenum = FreeFile()

  Open PathString + "\dictionary.txt" For Input As Filenum

  Wordfound = False

  Do While (Not EOF(Filenum))
    Input #Filenum, word
    If word = searchword Then
      Wordfound = True
      Exit Do
    End If
  Loop

  Close Filenum

  If (Wordfound) Then
    MsgBox word + " Found"
  Else
    MsgBox ("Word not Found")
  End If
'
End Sub
```